# Why can I catch multiple Exceptions on a catch block, but not put in multiple parameters in a method?

Tags: java, parameter-passing

Since Java 7, the following code is possible:

```
    try{
        ...
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException | SomeOtherException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but emulating the syntax in a method is not:

```
    public int test(int |double d){
        ...
    }
```

and instead this must be done

```
    public int test(int d){
        ...
    }
    public int test(double d){
        ...
    }
```

or this:

```
    public class Foo<E>{
        ...
        public int test(E something){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Why can't I do something so much simpler in a method like in the catch block? What makes the catch block different, (besides catching Exceptions and the fact that it is a block)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because this is how the language is designed. :)

Comment: A method can have different functionalities based on different parameter types.

Comment: In this case "just because" is a valid answer. If I post it would you accept it? ;-P

Comment: Thought there was something more to this.

Comment: You don't need `int | double` as double can store every possible `int` value. If you need to be able to take either use `test(Number n)` and you can pass either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax in the new `catch` clause is not a total deviation from OOP standard.

The compiler type for the `e` variable is the common superclass of all the exceptions you are declaring. So if you declare something like this,

```
catch (IllegalArgumentException | OutOfMemoryError e)
```

then the actual type of `e` is `Throwable`, which does make some sense. Inside the `catch` block therefore you cannot call methods specific to either of the two exceptions, but only methods present in the `Throwable` class.

In your example instead,

```
public int test(int | double d)
```

what would be the compile type of `d`? Java is statically typed, so this declaration would not make any sense.

So I think in the `try...catch` case you are able to statically type the variable through inheritance; in your example this is impossible, and that's why it's forbidden.

Comment: I tried something along the lines of `class A{} class B{}`, but when I tried to do `public int test(A|B d)`, it still doesn't compile, but both `class A` and `class B` are `Objects`. Why would it be forbidden then, or is it "just because Java works that way?"

Comment: I think that if you feel the need to declare `public int test(A|B d)`, but can or do not want to declare `public int test(Object d)`, then there is something wrong in your class design - since inside the function you could treat `d` only as an `Object` in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious. So I'll interpret that as "just because Java works that way."

Comment: I actually meant "because it wouldn't make sense" :)

Comment: FWIW it would "not make sense" only because Java's designers chose not to implement sum types. It makes beautiful and elegant sense in many other languages. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
        ...
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException | IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can't do this either, as `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`: Alternatives in a multi-catch statement cannot be related by subclassing

Answer (score 1):

When you catch multiple exceptions, the variable `e` has the type of the closest common super class, typically `Exception`. You can't do this with `int|double` since they do not have a common super-class (they are primitives).

You can do something similar with methods:

```
// Instead of 
public void test(IOException | NullPointerException e) {...
// Just write
public void test(Exception e) { ...
```

This will of-course accept all exceptions. To prevent this, you could write:

```
public void test(IOException e) {test2(e);}
public void test(NullPointerException e) {test2(e);}
private void test2(Exception e) { ...
```

You could argue that it will be usefull to use the `|` operator as a shorthand for this, but it just happens that you do this pretty rarely in the real world. So there have not been a desire to implement this.

On the other hand you often do this when catching exceptions. Before multi-catch was introduced in java you often saw stuff like this:

```
} catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    handleException(e);
} catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    handleException(e);
} catch(SomeOtherException e){
    handleException(e);
}
```

Comment: Aren't all classes sub-classes of object? So this can be done with any two classes?

Comment: Exactly. `int` and `double` are primitives though, so that won't work. You could of course cast the values, but then you might loose information.

Comment: But you very rarely want to do this. Either you accept all instances of the super type (and its subclasses) or you want to handle subclasses differently, e.g. access some method they declare.

Comment: I agree, thanks for your answer. I did try something like `class A{}, class B{}`, but when I did `public int test(A|B d)`, it still wouldn't compile.

Comment: Consider creating an interface `interface MyInterface {..`, let `A` and `B` implement that, and then use that as the argument type `test(MyInterface aOrB)`

Comment: The miracles of polymorphism :)